# Create dialog window without top bar

Tags: gui-construction

I made a nice little interface for the Pi to switch GPIOs by clicking a button. I use `CreateDialog` for it. In Linux I can, after having created the window, click on the top bar and then chose undecorate. That is then exactly what I want. Is there a way for `CreateDialog` to issue a window undecorated (without the top bar)? Or is there an alternative to `CreateDialog`?

```
CreateDialog[
 Row[{"Hello world ghjdghjdghjdghjdghjdghj\t", DefaultButton[]}], 
 WindowTitle -> "no need for it"]
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kuba: That was the needed input to find the solution. 
By browsing through the options of WindowFrame (not mentioned for CreateDialog) I found the answer to my question:

```
CreateDialog[
 Row[{"Hello world ghjdghjdghjdghjdghjdghj\t", DefaultButton[]}], 
 StyleDefinitions -> "Dialog.nb", WindowFrame -> "Frameless", 
 WindowSize -> All]
```